# More useful ajaxForm error responses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajaxform

I am working on a ajax form that submits to a Rails backend.  The database has two attributes that disallow duplicates.

If a form is submitted with an entry that causes a duplication, the server throws a 500 Internal Server Error response.  In the logs I get this:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_startups_on_name"
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_startups_on_name"
```

How can I get this information in my ajax response?  I wish to inform the user which field hit a duplicate entry (name or url).

Comment: Specifying an error callback doesn't work?

Comment: Error callback takes `textStatus`, `errorThrown`, and `jqXHR`.  The `textStatus` is just "error" in my case, and the `errorThrown` is "Internal Server Error".  I'm not sure about `jqXHR`

Comment: Try `jqXHR.responseText`

Comment: That contains a full HTML server error page response.  It does contain info about the error, but it's amongst a lot of other debug info.  If it's the only way, I should be able to make it work. Thanks!